# What is the definition of a 'helper' in CodeMirror registerHelper method

Tags: codemirror

I am looking at CodeMirror help and `registerHelper` is described as

> `CodeMirror.registerHelper(type: string, name: string, value: helper)`
>   Registers a helper value with the given `name` in the given namespace
>   (`type`). This is used to define functionality that may be looked up by
>   mode. ...
>
> http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#registerHelper

This does not explain what the `value` is, when is it called (it seems to be a function), or why `getHelpers` accepts a position.

Is helper similar to a mode, but providing non-visual annotations (for code lookups)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a value -- any value. How it will be used depends on the type of helper. For `"hint"`, it'll be a function providing completions at a given point in a document, for `"hintWords"`, it'll be an array of strings that form possible completions, for `"wordChars"`, it is a regular expression describing the characters that count as word characters for a mode, and so on.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose my confusion is because `getHelpers` says _"fetch the set of applicable helper values for the given position"_ -- how does it know which ones are applicable if there is nothing in value indicating position?

Comment: Well, yes, `getHelpers` will return an _array_, possibly containing more than one applicable helper value.

Comment: @AndreyShchekin Helpers are grouped by CodeMirror mode ("javascript", "css", etc.) based on the `name` argument passed to `registerHelper()` (not sure why the arg isn't just named `mode` instead). So to look up a helper you need both type _and_ mode/name. But CodeMirror mode can vary by cursor position -- think `<script>` tag inside HTML for example. CM takes the `pos` you pass `getHelpers()`, finds the mode at that pos, and uses the mode to look up the correct group of registered helpers.